# CodeIgniter Send Multiple Attachment Maximum File Size

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is the maximum file size in sending an email with attachment in codeigniter?
When i test my website it will only accept 24MB file attachment but i have more than 24MB. What is the best solution for this matter? THANKS!

```
    $id = 17;
    $email = "stephencabalida80@gmail.com";
    $this->load->library('email');
    $attach = $this->m_admin->getAttachment($id);

    $this->email->from('office@escaperoomfactory.net', 'Escaperoom Factory');
    $this->email->to(urldecode($email));
    $this->email->subject('Escaperoom Files');
    $this->email->message('Hi, Thank you for purchasing our game/s. Have Fun!');

    $path = 'upload/'.$id;

    foreach ($attach as $row) {
        $this->email->attach("".$path.'/'.$row->name."");
    }

    $this->email->send();`
```

Comment: This likely depends upon the settings within PHP itself.  There are a few settings you will want to check: upload_max_filesize, max_file_uploads, memory_limit, max_execution_time.  Beyond that, it might depend upon your mail server.

Comment: CodeIgniter doesn't impose such limitation. In addition to PHP settings, the mail server itself may also do that.

Comment: you can also try to upload this file to FTP and send only link to this large file via email